# Feed Import is successful and shows number of nodes imported but nodes not listed under content

Tags: 6, feeds

I am using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import content from a different Drupal site as xml.

The problem is that the feed import is successful, and a message says how many nodes of the new content type it has created. But when I go to content or to the database the content imported is nowhere to be seen.

What is the workaround for this issue? Is it a bug in the module?

Comment: Please tag question with Drupal version. And have you checked for errors? Cache problems?

Comment: Am importing into a Drupal 6 site. No errors thrown. I have checked the cache tables and the content isn't there (cache, ctools_object_cache) and there is nothing there. The logs speak of a page not found (instream/ad_status.js). I don't understand why it isn't working

Comment: @ClemensTolboom _Version tags should be used only for questions that apply to a version only, not to merely say what version a site is using._ In this case menting the Drupal version in text or comment would suffice (unless feeds is significantly different between Drupal versions).

Comment: @Neograph734 well the IP now told us it is Drupal 6 which is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is what I did for the nodes to be picked and listed under content:
For the importer, Mapping for Node Processor, added a source xpathparser mapped to target GUID and checked Unique target.
[image]
Then for XPath XML parser mapped the GUID field to the Node id field in my xml file (for my case the label was Nid) 
[image]

Comment: Nice. I think you can now mark your answer as 'the answer' too.

Comment: @ClemensTolboom you're right, though probably a little extra patience is needed to do so (a self answered question can only be accepted after 2 days ... I seem to remember). Agree?